# angular agm core map circle click not opening the agm info window

Tags: google-maps, angular6, angular-google-maps

I am using Angular 6 + AGM core to show google map geolocation. On click of agm-marker the agm-info-window displays but when i click agm-circle, the info window is not working.

```
        <agm-circle
            [latitude]="marker.latitude"
            [longitude]="marker.longitude"
            [radius]="marker.value * markerRadiusScaleFactor"
            (circleClick)="onCircleClicked($event)">
            <agm-info-window [isOpen]="visible">
                <app-map-info-window (close)="visible = false" [marker]="marker"></app-map-info-window>
            </agm-info-window>
        </agm-circle>
```

component.ts

```
onCircleClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log($event);
    this.visible = !this.visible;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: There is some issue with @agm/core version 3.0.0.beta version. The events don't work normally in case of agm-circle.
This link might help you: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1871

Answer (score 1):

To make the amg-info-window show up during mouse events (over or click),I needed to add the same latitude and longitude values as those for amg-circle  to the amg-info-window as well. This is not needed when using amg-marker instead of amg-info-circle. Looks like some inconsistency in angular-google-map implementation.

```
    <div *ngFor="let site of sites">
      <agm-circle *ngIf="site.active"
        [latitude]="site.latitude"
        [longitude]="site.longitude"
        [radius]="site.radius"
        [fillColor]="site.color"
        [fillOpacity]="site.opacity"
        (mouseOver)="infoWindow.open();"
        (mouseOut)="infoWindow.close();">

        <agm-info-window
          [latitude]="site.latitude"
          [longitude]="site.longitude"
          [disableAutoPan]="false" #infoWindow>

          <div>
              <span>
                <b>{{site.name +': '}} ({{site.budget | currency }}) </b>
              </span>
          </div>

        </agm-info-window>
      </agm-circle>
    </div>
```